# Crustal composition of an ammonia planet

Tags: planets, geology

I am currently building a planet that weighs about 4 earth masses and is 2.3 earth radii long. It is an ammonia planet (as the title suggests), and has ammonia oceans with some dissolved water ice, methanol and salts (sodium, chlorides, sulfates, potassium etc.). The average temperature is about 260ºK on the planet and the avg pressure at sea level is about 2.5 atm.

It has an ocean with the following composition:

- Ammonia: 80%
- Ice: 12% (which sinks under the ammonia and is mostly regular ice, but at very deep places, it may become ice III)
- Salts: 5.5%
- Ethanol: 2%
- Other: 0.5%

If you can't already tell, this solution is quite basic, so basic that a lot of common minerals that we have in our crust would simply dissolve. As a result, I would like to understand what minerals/compounds would be able to survive the fierce chemical weathering and make up the continental and oceanic crust. If you give percentages, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ammonia is a solvent, just like water. Ammonia simply dissolves the dissolvable faster than water will. But it still takes a lot of time to dissolve rock. I've never found ammonia-based biology believable due to how quickly it can dissolve bonds, but ignoring the organic component, the crust of Earth would be more than suitable as a model for your ammonia planet. If you want to test the theory, fill a mason jar half full of dirt and fill the rest with ammonia. Close the lid (to simulate a non-oxygen-based atmosphere) and wait a few weeks. Drain, dry, and look at the dirt that's still there.

Comment: Understood and agreed. The only issue with your theory is that over millions of years, all that ammonia is definitely going to dissolve at least some significant amount of stuff. That's why I asked this question, and I'm not able to find any resources on what/how much minerals dissolve in an ammonia/ice mixture (with some other stuff).

Comment: I would say volcanic activities make this a non issue as generally new crust is always forming. What i think is more of a problem is that the ammonia ocean may just dry up over time. The most probable way to avoid this maybe to have some highly resistant layer but Ii have no idea how it would form naturally.

Comment: One idea that may be possible is a diamond layer which is a far as i know very resistant to acid and yes there is indeed a diamond planet in the real world just look it up. So such s layer may keep the ammonia from dissolving everything.

Comment: The ammonia probably won't dry up because the skies rain down ammonia snow and rain, and to make the ammonia gaseous, you'd probably have to melt all the water ice too (as it forms a layer underneath the ammonia). The ice probably has a layer of rock underneath it where all the geological activity takes place (and maybe there are some areas where the ice becomes water near tectonic lavas). Is there any specific reason why you think the ocean will dry up?

Comment: If the ammonia ocean reacts with the oceans ice and builds it will build acid if the pressure down there doesn't prevent it. This accident will react with the silicon of the ocean floor. If this process continues for few 100 million years then eventually the sea level will eventually drop. While it may not completely dry up the ammonia there will less and less of it till eventually the water is used up. And i don't think there is a way this process is reversible especially at this scale.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock makes an excellent point about volcanism. It's why, after millions of years, water hasn't worn our world down to nothing. In other words, your world need only more volcanic to solve the problem. This lets you craft the crust based on Earth's with shifts in percentages to meet your world's needs.

Comment: If you world is too cold for liquid water the geothermal activity on the ocean floor is likely still able to melt it. And yes the magma is going to find through it.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock Understood. I just need more volcanic activity to make sure that the crust doesn't fizz away and it can probably be just like earth's. What can I do about the ocean dissolving (that wouldn't be very good).

Comment: That is a really difficult situation. Though maybe you could just have volcanoes spit out ammonia to replenish it. But i don't know how possible that would be. Alternatively you could just not have water near your ammonia no water = no acid. And that way your amonia won't be depleted. Though this may be a thing you don't want as you seem relatively fixed on the idea of acid oceans.

Comment: Unfortunately though there sadly cannot be a permanent layer of undissolvable rock due to volcanic activities. But i don't know the full story of it and someone may have a solution for it.

Comment: I really wish I could get rid of the water, but it will definitely be there no matter what because it is common in the universe (and create the ammonium acid). I do like the idea of cryogenic volcanos shooting out ammonia, but that probably won't solve the entire problem. One solution could be to let the ammonium form salts (ammonium chloride, ammonium sulfate, etc.) so it would not eat at the ocean floor as much. Another idea is to form a surface of HNSO polymers that wouldn't react with the acid by combining ammonia and sulfur dioxide, though I don't have SO2 in this setup currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152206/discussion-between-neil-iyer-and-fallenspacerock).

Comment: Lets go to chat. I have a link above and this comment chain is getting quite long.